# D separation from Spirtes paper

Tags: machine-learning, probability, conditional-probability, causality, d-separation

[image]Hi, i've been trying to learn d-separation and came across this figure in figure 4 (page 9) of Spirtes paper and i am a bit confuse.  In the paper, Spirtes says

> X4 is not d-separated from X1 given its parents X2 and X3 (see figure 4).

I can see why X4 is not d-separated from X1 given X3. But I don’t see why conditioning on X2 breaks the D-separation between X1 and X3 (or why conditioning on X2 is even necessary?). What am I missing? Any help would greatly be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Not sure which paper this is from (although Spirtes used a nearly identical graph in Figure 2. of Spirtes, P. (1995). [Directed Cyclic Graphical Representations of Feedback](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/spirtes95directed.html). In P. Besnard & S. Hanks (Eds.), *Eleventh Conference on Uncertainty in Artificial Intelligence*. Morgan Kaufmann Publishers, Inc.).

The key point is that **the Figure 4 which you excerpted is not a Directed *Acyclic* Graph**. The value of D separation in linking causal beliefs to statistical dependencies in order to inform counterfactual formal causal inference depends strongly on the "acyclical" portion of "DAG". For causal inference (and deduction) around *cyclic* graphs (i.e. there is a cycle of length two in Figure 4, made up of $X_3$ and $X_4$) you need to [look to other causal formalisms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/511944/44269).

Your confusion is understandable: I find that how *time* is (and is not) represented in DAGs is often glossed over. Bear the following in mind:

- **DAGs imply some temporal ordering among variables:** $A \to B$ in a DAG means that $A$ occurred *before* $B$: causal ordering implies temporal ordering. Likewise $A \to B \to C$ means that both $A$ and $B$ occurred before $C$, as well as $A$ occurring before $B$.
- **DAGs do not necessarily imply temporal ordering among *all* variables:** In the DAG where $X \to Y$ and $Z \to Y$ (I just ran out of MathJax/LaTeX chops, sorry ;) both $X$ and $Z$ occur before $Y$, but the DAG (and the logic that follows from it *a la* D separation, etc.) says *nothing* about the temporal ordering of $X$ and $Z$ with respect to one another: either may occur first, or they may occur simultaneously, and the DAG is still valid.
- **DAGs do not imply *quantitative* timing:** The causal logic of D separation (or lack thereof) of the variables appearing in a DAG applies *regardless* of when on the clock or calendar variable phenomena occurred (temporal ordering aside).
- **Directed cyclic graphs represent time differently:** In the causal formalisms using directed cyclic graphs which I am familiar with, the causal graph represents variables at *all times* during which the DCG is valid/exists. (I think of it as looking 'head on' at the arrow of time.) For example, Figure 4 implies (among other things) that $X_{3,t-1} \to X_{4,t}$, $X_{3,t} \to X_{4,t+1}$, $X_{3,t+1} \to X_{4,t+2}$, etc. You *could* re-represent Figure 4 as a DAG, but then:

  (i) you have to make decisions about things like lags (i.e. does $X_{3,t-1} \to X_{4,t+2}$?),

  (ii) you have to make a decision about whether you will capture some event like 'the beginning of time' where $t=1$ in a physical/natural sense, and possibly the end of time as well,

  (iii) you gonna need *many* variables and arrows and your calculations are going to get combinatorically challenging. (You might get by using a "probabilistic graph template," which some of the folks doing data processing with Bayesean probabilistic causal graphs are familiar with.)
- **This point about "all times" applies to non-looped variables in DCGs also:** Figure 4 implies $X_{1,t-1} \to X_{3,t}$, $X_{1,t} \to X_{3,t+1}$, etc. Same point about lags here as well.

This should give you a good insight as to why DCGs break D separation in the way Spites, Pearl, etc. talk about it (pick some point in time and draw a conclusion about D separated paths… then realize that the variables from 1 step in time backward from where your analysis was make for as yet unaccounted for open backdoor paths, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think DCG breaks D separation only in special cases. There are cases where DCG doesn't break D-separation. Specifically,  in Theorem 1 of the paper: Directed Cyclic Graphical Representations of Feedback, Sprite says that D-separation applies both to acyclic and cyclic graph in linear SEM.

Comment: @Alim Well, that's what Spirtes says, but he does a poor job of defining feedback in my experience with him, and I disagree and reassert that the structural causal models/counterfactual formal causal inference folks do not have actual tools for analyzing complex causal systems defined by feedback. Which paper are you reading? See my [4th and 5th comment here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/483390/44269) for a little more critique on Sprites and DCGs.